# drupal function theming for custom menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i have a custom menu with three levels. It is in format:

```
- a/b1/c1   - a/b2/c2   - a/b3/c3
```

I want to have same css formatting for all the b1, b2, b3 and same formatting in c1,c2,c3 but different between them. I have found that the function that renders that menu is: `theme_menu_item_link()` But the same function renders the b1 and c1 too. Is there a way to separate them in templates.php and have them format them differently. Is there any other way around. Thank u in advance people

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) if you want to make a tree like menu structure.